# From where the DirectoryEntry class of c# fetches data?

Tags: c#, directoryentry

Where does the DirectoryEntry class fetches data from?

Answer (score 2):

Arun I think you are very new to this area. Use google and msdn. You can also use articles or books related with active directory and c#

Answer (score 1):

A very unclear question; the short answer is AD - have you looked at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx)?